# iPhone SDK: Call tableview function anywhere

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I wanted to know if there was a way to call the tableview function anywhere throughtout the program. What I mean is I want to call this function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

anywhere in my code. is there anyway of using the self function or anything or if its possible at all? Thanks.

Comment: Why? That method is only used by the table view to provide cells for the table. What are you trying to achieve by calling this from anywhere?

Comment: Are you trying to reloadData?

Comment: I'm trying to break down an error with the table view and when I put a breakpoint on this method it seems to only go through when you launch the app but not while its running, I'm looking for an alternative to calling this method from something like a void function so maybe I can break it down from there.

Comment: What's the error and where is the error coming from?

Answer (score 2):

You sure can. You just have to be able to pass an `NSIndexPath` object to it, like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Once `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns your cell object, you can access its properties, etc. like:

```
cell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.0;
```

Also, if you are using a custom UITableViewCell, you can get your custom cell returned by type casting the call:

```
MyCustomCellClass *cell = (MyCustomCellClass *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call [tableview reloadData];  this will call cell for row at index path.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
  // First do modifications in the datasource for table     
    // And then you can reload the specific row like this:

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

And the reason your cellForRowAtIndexPath is not calling may be because you did not set the delegate OR there are no visible rows on the UI to display as Table calls this function for the rows which are visible on screen so check the frame of your table too.